# Running both morning and evening everyday

Tags: bellyfat

i am skinny fat & badly wanted to **reduce belly fat**. I am not such powerfull boy at the age of **26**. maximum i can run **half an hour** in **morning** , so may i run half an hour in **evenin**g also , is that fine ? or is it better to take some rest in morning and run for half an hour again.

Comment: This question is completely different seniors ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not  specialist in specifying how you  lose more calories: running morning or running evening. But I can say for you, to lose you belly fat you should lose some pounds totally since you can't  do a spot reduction  of fats from your body. What is important through out your routine is to maintain calorie less than calorie out, so try to do  workout so that you are  in a calorie deficit, whether you do it at  morning or at evening is not a matter.

Comment: so howmuch ever i eat also that's not an issue, but main thing i should eat less calories, than i burn, so i need to eat more proteins with less claories and avoid carbohydrates which have more calories, thanks for answer......

Comment: YEs,  it is all about calorie balance. Keep in mind that even fats have more calories than carbohydrates.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to lose belly fat you should be aiming to increase your testosterone and GH levels by doing high intensity exercise, for example sprinting. This will also increase your metabolism which will help you to use more calories.

Comment: You are aware that you can't spot reduce a specific area of the body, correct?

Comment: I dont think this answer is the suitable response for the question. the user is asking about running morning and evening for half an hour vs running morning one hour woth some rest between each half of the hour.